# Display picture on mouse hover over link

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

on may page I have a list of three links. I want an image to appear at the cursor position when it hovers over the link. Unfortunately the same image appears over all three links. I need the picture to be different for each link.

```js
let attached = false;
 
let imageContainer = document.querySelector("#image");

const followMouse = (event) => {
  imageContainer.style.left = event.x + "px";
  imageContainer.style.top = event.y + "px";
}

function showImage() {
  if (!attached) {
    attached = true;
    imageContainer.style.display = "block";
    document.addEventListener("pointermove", followMouse);
  }
}

function hideImage() {
  attached = false;
  imageContainer.style.display = "";
  document.removeEventListener("pointermove", followMouse);
}
```

```css
#image {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"onpointerenter="showImage()" onpointerleave="hideImage()">COLUMNS</a>
                                              
<div id="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Mammisi_Philae2.JPG/340px-Mammisi_Philae2.JPG"></div>


<a href="#"onpointerenter="showImage()" onpointerleave="hideImage()">ROOF</a>
                                              
<div id="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg/384px-Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg"></div>

<a href="#"onpointerenter="showImage()" onpointerleave="hideImage()">ROOF</a>
                                              
<div id="image"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/126_rue_de_rivoli_Paris_2012_10.jpg/340px-126_rue_de_rivoli_Paris_2012_10.jpg"></div>
```

Is there a simple way to show a different picture for each link? Can it be achieved by passing a different image src for each link to the JS showImage function? Thank you for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by refactoring multiple part of your code:

## Step 1

Move the images inside of the `a` tag so you can easily link the image to the right link:

```html
<a href="#" onpointerenter="showImage()" onpointerleave="hideImage()">
  ROOF
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg/384px-Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg">
</a>
```

## Step 2

Add the element that trigger the events to manipulate it in javascript with the `showImage` and `hideImage` functions:

## Step 3

Hide and show the image in the link according to the events.

You and up with this kind of code implementation:

```js
let attached = false;

const getElmtImage = (elmt) => {
  return elmt.querySelector("img")
}

const followMouse = (elmt, event) => {
  elmt.style.left = event.x + "px";
  elmt.style.top = event.y + "px";
}

function showImage(elmt) {
  const image = getElmtImage(elmt)
  if (!attached) {
    attached = true;
    image.style.display = "block";
    document.addEventListener("pointermove", function(event) {
      followMouse(image, event)
    });
  }
}

function hideImage(elmt) {
  const image = getElmtImage(elmt)
  attached = false;
  image.style.display = "none";
  document.removeEventListener("pointermove", followMouse);
}
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onpointerenter="showImage(this)" onpointerleave="hideImage(this)">
  COLUMNS
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Mammisi_Philae2.JPG/340px-Mammisi_Philae2.JPG">
</a>

<a href="#" onpointerenter="showImage(this)" onpointerleave="hideImage(this)">
  ROOF
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg/384px-Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg">
</a>

<a href="#" onpointerenter="showImage(this)" onpointerleave="hideImage(this)">
  ROOF
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/126_rue_de_rivoli_Paris_2012_10.jpg/340px-126_rue_de_rivoli_Paris_2012_10.jpg">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

All your images have the same selector (id of #image)

I did with jquery

```js
$("div.image").hide();
  $(".img-link").hover(function() {
    $(this).children("img").css('display', 'inline');
  }, function() {
    $(this).children("img").css('display', 'none');
  });
```

```css
img {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <a href="#"  class="img-link" >
    COLUMNS
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/33/Mammisi_Philae2.JPG/340px-Mammisi_Philae2.JPG">
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="img-link">
    ROOF
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/42/Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg/384px-Strasbourg_Aubette_03.jpg">
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="img-link">
    ROOF
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/126_rue_de_rivoli_Paris_2012_10.jpg/340px-126_rue_de_rivoli_Paris_2012_10.jpg">
  </a>
```